Animation about drivers teleporting then racing against dark robots in cars with special powers
I once saw an animated movie/series about people racing against sort of dark robots.
They were with a group of people and they went to a really distant place over a road that was route 66 or another route and then they teleported to a place with race cars. 
They were all getting in their car and waiting for the traffic lights to turn green so they could race.
The robots could also use cards which gave them all kinds of advantages like the whole car becoming really thin so they can fit through small places etc. They have to race on a road with obstacles and if they don't win something happens to them. 
This is all I remember but I can't seem to find the movie or series, can anyone help me?

Please don't use generic titles like "What is the name of this movie"! I've fixed it this time...

How long ago did you see this? Was it computer animation or more hand drawn style?

Was it a full movie, a short, a series?  Timeframe when you saw this and when it might have been made?  You need to add a good amount of more detail.

Is it
Hot Wheels: Highway 35 World Race

Follows a teenager called Vert Wheeler 

as he is invited to World Race by Dr. Peter Tezla. Vert drives to a secret location in the Californian desert and learns about a race that takes place on Highway 35, which to enter, each driver must be doing 300 mph at a specific location to open a portal. 

There are various teams in this, with names like Roadbeasts, Scorchers and Street Breed, but the main protagonist is Zed-36 who is aided by CLYP robots under the control of Gelorum, herself a robot.
CLYP Robot:

Gelorum

The races take place in various dangerous locations like inside a volcano, with obstructions that are in keeping with the theme of the local i.e. lava in the volcano.
Or possibly it's sequel 
Hot Wheels AcceleRacers

Set two years after World Race, Gelorum is back but the CLYP robots are replaced with Drones.
Drone:
 
In this series they can use special devices called Accelechargers that allow a car to use powers.  The accelecharger materialises inside the car and hovers until the driver picks it up. It is shaped like a rectangle and has a symbol on it.
accelechargers in a cockpit

Here are some accelecharger close ups
 
They look like cards.
Different realms gave different abilities. Here are some

Monument Realm AcceleCharger (2-D): Allows the vehicle to become two
dimensional---can cut through other cars. 
Micro Realm AcceleCharger   (Size Scaler): Allows cars to change size. 
Solar Realm Accelecharger
(Anti Gravitation): Allows a car to manipulate/control gravity.
Labyrinth Realm AcceleCharger (Navigator): Manipulates a car's GPS
System and pinpoints all the right directions and that lead to the
finish line.
Cavern Realm AcceleCharger (Night Sight): Allows the driver to see in total darkness.

